# How to return empty array if file doesn't exists in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, fs

I would like to console.log a message and return an empty array if I try to read a file that doesn't exist. The getAllNotes function fires effective and the error is definitely thrown `no such file or directory, open 'notes.json'`.

However, why is the error thrown if I didn't specify `throw err` in my if statement? Secondly why doesn't my console.log message get outputted and the empty array not returned?

```
var getAllNotes = () => {
  console.log("MADE IT TO GET ALL NOTES")
  var notesArray = fs.readFileSync('notes.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("There are no notes to display");
      return [];
    } else {
      console.log("DATA",data)
      console.log("MADE IT TO PARSE")
      return JSON.parse(data);
    }
  });
  console.log("INSIDE GET ALL NOTES", notesArray)
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs.readFileSync` is a blocking call and doesn't take a callback in the same way that `fs.readFile` does. It simply returns the contents of the file, see the below example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var date = fs.readFileSync('myfile', 'utf8');
console.log(data);
```

When I ran your example an exception is thrown because you are providing a callback function where it is expecting a string or object for the options parameter.

You can do a blocking call with `fs.existsSync(path)` to check if the file exists before trying to read it.

Alternatively you can use the non-blocking version of the readFile and provide the callback as you were trying to do.

Comment: Oh my goodness. That fixed the problem. What a great learning opportunity...  I would really like to know how you determined from reading the error message that it was expecting a string or object from the options parameter because I am rereading those errors and all I can take away is that the file I am trying to read doesn't exist.

Comment: So all I did was copy your example, add the require for fs and add a line to call your `getAllNotes()`. When I then ran this with `nodejs` I got this exception: `TypeError: Expected options to be either an object or a string, but got function instead`. Are you running it in the same way?